# Overlap or Override bottom title-strip with keyboard

Tags: android, xml, pagertitlestrip

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vp_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/st_tabs_main"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fl_toolbar" />

<in.lastlocal.l2v1.tabs.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/st_tabs_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>`
```

This is simple xml I'm using for bottom title, stripped with view pager. But when I click edit text of fragment page, keyboard is popping and pushing SlidingTab layout with, which I don't want how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try set android:windowSoftInputMode to adjustNothing or adjustPan in manifest at your activity.

```
    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

Comment: oh its is working , but I want to ignore certain view only to be adjusted <br>not whole page.